# finding specific string in ios dyld_shared_cache

Tags: ida, arm, ios

Im trying to find the library inside a dyld cache that contains a specific string.
I grepped the cache file and for the offset of the string, however when im throwing the cache file to ida non of the libraries match the specific offset.
how can i find which library include that string without analyzing 1gb file ?
thanks!